# How to change all identical objects in an array in Python?

Tags: python, class, pointers, object, instance

So, I have some class and I decided to create an objet and add it at different index into my list.

It gives me something like this:

```
[
 <__main__.MyClass instance at 0x7f2fc8c5a878>, 
 <__main__.MyClass instance at 0x7f2fc8c5a878>,
 <__main__.MyClass instance at 0x7f2fc8c5a878>,
  ...
]
```

Now, I create a second instance of my class `<__main__.MyClass instance at 0x7f48708e6878>`

I would like that changing the first element of my list results in changing other elements in the rest of my list which are of the same instance.

Is it possible to do this?

I can not simply iterating trough the list to 'manually' reassign the values because my real problem is a list of list etc.
Like this (A, B and C are 3 instances of the same class):

```
[[A, A, A],                             [[A, A, A],
[B, B, B],  -> if test(A, B): B = A ->  [A, A, A]
[C, C, C]]                              [C, C, C]]
```

Comment: Why are you storing so many references to the same object in the first place?

Comment: You could only do this is the object in question was itself a mutable container (e.g. a nested `list`) and you changed its contents to match that of the second instance.